# Automatically apply sharing mode of sub-folders to public in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, clickonce

When there are updates Clickonce increments a version of application and put the new application to a new folder. My problem is the new folder that contains new application is locked(only accessible by the folder owner) so when end users try to download the new application the page appears with 403 Forbidden error unless i changed the folder's permission manually. Does Ubuntu have some configuration to inherit permission settings from the parents folder when creating new folder? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have to use the setgid permission on parent directory.

The setgid bit on the directory only affects the group permissions, and means two things:

1) Any files created under that directory inherits the group ownership.
2) Any directories created under that directory inherit the setgid bit, AND the group ownership.

There is no other effect. Any mode, other than group ownership is controlled by the umask at the time of file/directory creation.

The user's ownership is controlled by the user creating the file or directory.